# Why is this Linq Where Clause not filtering the results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new to Linq and MVC and it has taken a lot of searching and learning to get to this point.

I have the following method that successfully receives the parameter "code".

```
    public ActionResult GetIssueList(string code)
    {
        //dynamic fill of project code dropdown on selection of customer code drop down
        ProjectManager pm = new ProjectManager();

        var projectcodes = pm.SelectAllProjects();
        var projects = new List<Project>();

        foreach (var proj in projectcodes)
        {
            projects.Add(proj as Project);
        }
        return Json(projects.Where(x => x.CustomerCode == code).ToList());
    }
```

The data is being retrieved from the database but the where clause does not filter out data that is equal to the parameter.

Comment: You could use `projectcodes.Cast<Project>().Where(...)` instead of manually populating a new list.

Comment: I don't know why the other comment was removed, but what is the type of `x.CustomerCode`? Is it a string, an enum, or what?

Comment: And what does `pm.SelectAllProject()` return ?

Comment: Thanks tuespetre. I've just tried "return Json(projectcodes.Cast<Project>().Where(x => x.CustomerCode == code));" but this didn't filter either. x.CustomerCode is a string.

Comment: pm.SelectAllProject returns all data from table Project. Currently just 4 records for testing.

Comment: your code can be simplified to, `return Json(pm.SelectAllProjects().Cast<Project>().Where(p => p.CustomerCode == code).ToList());`

Comment: Do you end up with too few or too many rows? How does the filter fail?

Comment: Thanks Jodrell - I've just tried that statement but it fails. By failing I mean the where clause is ineffective, all the rows from the database are returned.

Comment: Might be a question of case sensitivity. Try changing `Where(x => x.CustomerCode == code)` to something like `Where(x => x.CustomerCode.Equals(code,System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`.

Comment: Check if `x.CustomerCode` and `code` have differing space(s) in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many unknowns here to answer more precisely, but to more easily debug step-by-step, I suggest you change the `Where` call to a traditional loop (and change it back once you found the problem, of course):

```
public ActionResult GetIssueList(string code)
{
    IEnumerable<Project> projects =
        new ProjectManager()
        .SelectAllProjects()
        .Cast<Project>();

    //this is replacement for Where call.
    //Debug breakpoint here step by step and look at the CustomerCode values
    //to find out why they are all added.
    List<Project> filtered = new List<Project>();
    foreach(Project p in projects)
    {
        if(p.CustomerCode == code)
            filtered.Add(p);
    }

    return Json(filtered);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this David - I've tried it and it filters out as expected. Turns out I'm doing something wrong in the Jquery that binds this to a drop down list. My original post is filtering so I guess this is now closed. I've marked this as answered because it put me down the right track. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Debug through execution and make sure that the items certainly do not have the `CustomerCode` of `code`. My question for you though is "are the items in projectcodes `Project` objects? if they are not, you cannot `as cast` them to `Project`, but instead must make `new Projects` with that code `new Project(projectCode)`

Also, everything you had written above could easily be re-written as one line of code. (you may have to do a `.ToList<Project>()` before the `Where`, but I don't know your types so I won't assume)

```
public ActionResult GetIssueList(string code)
{
    return Json(new ProjectManager()
        .SelectAllProjects()
        .Select(proj => proj as Project)
        .Where(proj => proj.CustomerCode == code)
        .ToList();
}
```

**Edit**: Place a breakpoint in your above method on the return statement, and check before the comparison happens if the items in the list have the expected CustomerCode.

Comment: Thanks Ben - The items in projectcodes are objects returned from this method        " public List<Project> SelectAllProjects()
        {
            using (IssueViewContext context = new IssueViewContext())
            {
                return context.Projects.ToList();
            }
        }"